# C++ thread ending

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

I am trying to learn some proper thread management and I'm having some issues with this contrived example. The idea is the 'Holder' class can initiate a job which is an instance of a 'Wait' class which triggers a thread to do-some-stuff (wait for a period) and then call a callback in the 'Holder' to do some clean-up or what not.
I put the 'Wait' instance in a std::vector and when the callback tells me it is done. I remove it from the list.

**Update:** Corrected commented out line

> //waitlist.erase(it); // dump the wait object

**If I call the line above to indicate the job is done and remove it from 'the list', it causes the main thread to exit prematurely, why? What would be the correct way to remove it?**

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using Time = std::chrono::system_clock;
using Seconds = std::chrono::seconds;
using Timepoint = Time::time_point;

class Wait {
private:
    Timepoint target;
    std::thread thread;

public:
    Wait(unsigned int waitFor, unsigned short id, std::function<void(unsigned int)> callback_)
    {
        std::cout << "new Wait objet needs to wait for: " << waitFor << " seconds" << std::endl;
        target = Time::now() + Seconds(waitFor);

        // Create a thread to notify us when complete

        thread = std::thread([callback_, waitFor, id]() {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(Seconds(waitFor));
            std::cout << "from thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
            callback_(id);
        });
        
    }

    bool isDone() 
    {
        Timepoint now = Time::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float> difference = now - target;
        return (difference.count() > 0); // Thanks @Jesper
    }
};

class Holder {
private:
    std::vector<Wait> waitlist;

public:
    unsigned short addTask(unsigned int waitFor)
    {
        unsigned int sz = waitlist.size();
        waitlist.push_back(Wait(waitFor, sz, std::bind(&Holder::callback, this, std::placeholders::_1)));

        return waitlist.size() - 1;
    }

    bool isDone(unsigned int n) 
    {
        if (waitlist.size() >= n) {
            return waitlist.at(n).isDone();
        } 
        else return false; // failed
    }

    void callback(unsigned int id)
    {
        std::cout << "All done with Wait object" << std::endl;
        
        auto it = waitlist.begin() + id;
        /* comment/uncomment next line*/
        //waitlist.erase(it); // dump the wait object
    }
};

int main() 
{
    Holder h;
    // Create a task which spawns a thread, which notifies us when complete
    unsigned int id1 = h.addTask(3);
    
    // Just to show that while main thread is running, the completion status
    // of thread changes
    for (auto c = 0; c < 5; c++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(Seconds(1));
        std::cout << "from main: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << " - " << h.isDone(id1) << std::endl;
    }

    // Just to show the main thread continues on. It doesn't when line mentioned 
    // earlier is uncommented
    while(1) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(Seconds(1));
        std::cout << "Doing other stuff.." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
new Wait objet needs to wait for: 3 seconds
from main: 140234566031168 - 0
from main: 140234566031168 - 0
from thread: 140234566026816
All done with Wait object
from main: 140234566031168 - 1
from main: 140234566031168 - 1
from main: 140234566031168 - 1
Doing other stuff..
Doing other stuff..
Doing other stuff..
Doing other stuff..
Doing other stuff..
```

Any insights/guidance into what what (I'm sure basic) premise, I've overlooked, would be appreciated.

Paul

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. `waitlist.pop_back();` is not called in the shown code. Don't make SO users to guess where you call it.

Comment: Remember that if you don't `.join()` your threads, then there's no guarantee that they are done running (or have even started to run) when your process (main thread) exits and what happens to your threads when the main process terminates is implementation defined (on Windows child threads keep running, on Linux they are forcefully terminated - for example) - always `join` your threads.

Comment: In C++20, you can use `std::jthread`s to automatically enforce the `join()`s  that @JesperJuhl mentioned.

Comment: Note that code like `while(1)` is *very likely* to exhibit [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) unless the code *in* the loop does very specific things; like modify a `volatile` variable, cause I/O to happen and a few other things - be wary of such (seemingly infinite) loops.

Comment: "`using Seconds = std::chrono::seconds;`" - Why? Why not just use `using namespace std::chrono_literals;` and then use (for example) `42s` when you want 42 seconds?

Comment: "`if (difference.count() > 0) return true;
        else return false;`" - is overly verbose; just `return difference.count() > 0;`.

Comment: Thanks @273K - Noted and corrected. I'd corrected the example prior to posting and missed updating the commented out line =/

Comment: Thanks @jesper.  When reading about the chrono literals, I couldn't see how to suffix them to variable names and get them to work, so I just did what worked for the time being. i.e. "Seconds(waitFor)" works, but I can't get "(waitFor)s" to work, so there must be a syntax thing I've missed there.

Comment: Thanks @Jesper. Your return clean up is much nicer =)

Comment: Thanks @Jesper. With respect to join(), my understanding is that is blocking. I want the thread to go on by itself and only callback when done., which leaves me wondering if I don't want a blocking behaviour, do I need it, and if so where to put it? If I put it in the callback of Holder, I'll need to expose the thread from Wait to 'join'.

Comment: Thank @Jesper. For the while(1), I just did that to show that the main continued on with the waitlist.erase(it) commented out and exited early when not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I understand what I was doing wrong. The callback (which was executed from the instantiated thread in the Wait object), was trying to delete the Wait object that housed the thread, which calls the destructor of the thread and causes the main thread to exist.

Using std::async gets around the join/detach issue (similar I guess to the std::jthread option for C++20 mentioned above), but you can simply check if it is finished with something like;

```
if (async_task.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) // async done
```

Once I have a way to check it is completed, I can simply check if complete and then remove the task from the vector in the "Holder" class.

I couldn't do the same thing with threads because if I used join(), I'd have to wait on it and I didn't want a blocking call and if I used detach(), it would decouple it from the main instance and I would not know when / if it finished. If the instantiated thread terminates without seeing either of these, it causes the main thread to terminate which is why I wasn't getting to the 'Doing other stuff...' part after the thread terminated.